# Multiple layer pdf export from matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, document, layer

I have a problem with graphs that has much more lines than one, but they all has to be on one graph(they are measured together). As a result i have to create multiple layer pdf so that person that will read this pdf can turn on/off all the graphs lines separately. Most of pdf readers are capable of layer recognition. Is there any way to create multi layer pdf from matplotlib?

Layer 1: everything but lines on graphs(text, axis, grids, pictures, legend)
Layer 2: 1st measurement
...
Layer 4: nth measurement

**Example code to work with:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Generate random data for 5 lines
data = []
for i in range(5):
    x = [j for j in range(10)]
    y = [random.random() for j in range(10)]
    data.append((x, y))

# Plot the lines
for x, y in data:
    plt.plot(x, y)

# Show the plot
plt.savefig("graph.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Expected result: pdf file with multiple layers.